# Openpyxl - Use imported function in another file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a Workbook with several sheets where I want to run the same function on every sheet.
To have a more clean code, I have split the Workbook sheets in different python modules.

In file sheet_1.py, I have the following function:

```
>>>sheet_1.py
#This adds the text "Month: April" in the last row, first column cell
def addTitle():
    for col in ws2.iter_cols(min_row=ws2.max_row, max_row=ws2.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
        for cell in col:
            cell.value = "Month: April"

    wb2.save(destination)
    wb2.close()
```

I want to use the same function(That adds "Month: April"), to run on sheet_2.py and other sheets (sheet_3.py...)

How may I do this, as right now, if I do the following:

```
>>>sheet_2.py
from sheet_1 import addTitle
addTitle()
```

This will run addTitle on sheet_1.py instead of sheet_2.py

I'm sure, I'm missing something here...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just open your Workbook in one `.py` file and iterate through all over sheets on it. Actually is not needed to run it on separated scripts.

There is a method in openpyxl called `.get_sheet_names()`. Use it to get a list of all sheets in your workbook and iterate through it:

```
list_of_sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
for sheet in list_of_sheets:
ws = wb[sheet]
    for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=ws.max_row, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1,   max_col=1):
        for cell in col:
            cell.value = "Month: April"
```

At the end you'll have one unique `.py` script that does everything you need.

Comment: True, but I did this because there are several different functions running on each sheet and in order to do proper modifications, I had to keep the separately.
Furthermore, I need to run this function on just a couple of sheets, not on every sheet.

Comment: You can set a list of sheets that you want to run through and use it at `for` statement instead.